# Compare Two Value Of Table Cell To Add Class If The Same

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem in comparing two cell value right now. Before I was using `onclick` function to get specific cell value. Therefore I can easily compare two item but now I need to automatically compare two items and add bootstrap class success if they are the same. The code I am using right now are here below.

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/aice09/ynh8wfc9/

```js
var tables = document.getElementsByClassName('tb_jobsched');
var rows = tables[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');

var data = tables.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
var poqty = data[5];
var stock= data[7];

var newpoqty = poqty .replace("PCS", "");
var newstocks = stock.replace("PCS", "");

if (newpoqty === newstocks) {
  rows[i].classList.add("success");
} else {

}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table id="tb_jobsched" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>CUSTOMER</td>
      <td>PO QUANTITY</td>
      <td>DATE OF DELIVERY</td>
      <td>STOCKS</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>CUSTOMER 1</td>
    <td>2000 PCS</td>
    <td>2017/06/15</td>
    <td>5000 PCS</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>CUSTOMER 2</td>
    <td>500 PCS</td>
    <td>2017/06/15</td>
    <td>500 PCS</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: check `var newpoqty = qtyperbox.replace("PCS", "");
var newstocks = qtyperbox.replace("PCS", "");` same i think you need to change values? also you can `Number()` so you dont need to use replace

Comment: `var newpoqty = qtyperbox.replace("PCS", ""); var newstocks = qtyperbox.replace("PCS", "");` didn't affect the coz it just remove the string value @guradio

Comment: `qtyperbox` is not defined in the code shown. Is the question "How do I add a class to a table row if the contents of its second and fourth cells are the same?" That is, you're trying to compare PO QUANTITY to STOCKS?

Comment: Maybe fix the jsfiddler first. I am seeing errors about `jquery` library not getting imported.

Comment: Codes has been updated. Please help me on sirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const rows = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable tbody tr');

rows.forEach((row) => {
 const cells = row.getElementsByTagName('td');
  const poQty = cells[1].innerText;
  const stocks = cells[3].innerText;
  
  if (poQty === stocks) {
   row.classList.add('success');
  }
});
```

```css
.success {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>CUSTOMER</td>
      <td>PO QUANTITY</td>
      <td>DATE OF DELIVERY</td>
      <td>STOCKS</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>CUSTOMER 1</td>
      <td>2000 PCS</td>
      <td>2017/06/15</td>
      <td>5000 PCS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CUSTOMER 2</td>
      <td>500 PCS</td>
      <td>2017/06/15</td>
      <td>500 PCS</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var tables = document.getElementsByClassName('tb_jobsched');
var rows = tables[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');

for(var i = 0; i< rows.length; i++) {
 var childs = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
  var potqty = childs[1].innerHTML.replace('PCS', '');
  var stock = childs[3].innerHTML.replace('PCS', '');
  if(potqty === stock) {
   rows[i].className += 'success';
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>CUSTOMER</td>
      <td>PO QUANTITY</td>
      <td>DATE OF DELIVERY</td>
      <td>STOCKS</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="tb_jobsched">
    <tr>
      <td>CUSTOMER 1</td>
      <td>2000 PCS</td>
      <td>2017/06/15</td>
      <td>5000 PCS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CUSTOMER 2</td>
      <td>500 PCS</td>
      <td>2017/06/15</td>
      <td>500 PCS</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```